# Why the jvm load classes from a jar when no one is really requiring it?

Tags: java, classloader

My application uses a lot of classes, spread over many jars, so I would like to create a classpath with ordered jars, based on the order of class loading. This would decrease startuo time when all these jars are on a network/remote file system.

I started experimenting with `java -verbose:class -classpath ... mainclass` and check what was loaded. Adding new jars when getting `ClassNotFoundException`.

I then noticed that a few classes are loaded every time, without my application really using it. I just made an example: an empty class with an empty start method. Even loadind this class, require a lot of other jars.

```
package test;
public class CheckClassLoader {
  static public void main (String args[]) {
  }
}
```

Please note that this class is included in a large jar that contains a lot of other classes.

This is my output. It show that a bounch of classes I wrote (not standard java, nor classes from externa jars I use) are loaded.

```
$ java -verbose:class -Xdiag -jar Neos.jar test.CheckClassLoader \
  | egrep -v 'Loaded (sun|java|javax|org\.xml)\.'
[Opened /home/giuseppe/jdk1.7.0_15/jre/lib/rt.jar]
[Loaded gui.sendto.SendToListener from file:/tmp/Neos.jar]
[Loaded gui.ParentChildFrameIfc from file:/tmp/Neos.jar]
[Loaded gui.ParentChildFrame from file:/tmp/Neos.jar]
[Loaded gui.MainFrame from file:/tmp/Neos.jar]
[Loaded utils.MessageException from file:/tmp/Neos.jar]
[Loaded exchange.xml.XmlImportReader from file:/tmp/Neos.jar]
[Loaded gui.ParentChildFrame$7 from file:/tmp/Neos.jar]
[Loaded engine.TableBean from file:/tmp/Neos.jar]
[Loaded utils.io.net.ConnectionListener from file:/tmp/Neos.jar]
[Loaded utils.image.ByteDocTools from file:/tmp/Neos.jar]
[Loaded gui.utils.FileFilterExtension from file:/tmp/Neos.jar]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/PDDocument
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2451)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2694)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1622)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(LauncherHelper.java:494)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:486)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
... 6 more
```

The last part of the complete output (not filtered with `egrep`) is:

```
[Loaded engine.TableBean from file:/tmp/Neos.jar]
[Loaded java.io.IOException from /home/giuseppe/jdk1.7.0_15/jre/lib/rt.jar]
[Loaded utils.io.net.ConnectionListener from file:/tmp/Neos.jar]
[Loaded utils.image.ByteDocTools from file:/tmp/Neos.jar]
[Loaded javax.swing.filechooser.FileFilter from /home/giuseppe/jdk1.7.0_15/jre/lib    /rt.jar]
[Loaded gui.utils.FileFilterExtension from file:/tmp/Neos.jar]
[Loaded java.io.FileNotFoundException from /home/giuseppe/jdk1.7.0_15/jre/lib/rt.jar]
[Loaded java.lang.NoSuchMethodException from /home/giuseppe/jdk1.7.0_15/jre/lib/rt.jar]
Exception in thread "main" [Loaded java.lang.Throwable$PrintStreamOrWriter from /home/giuseppe/jdk1.7.0_15/jre/lib/rt.jar]
[Loaded java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintStream from /home/giuseppe/jdk1.7.0_15/jre/lib/rt.jar]
[Loaded java.util.IdentityHashMap from /home/giuseppe/jdk1.7.0_15/jre/lib/rt.jar]
[Loaded java.util.IdentityHashMap$KeySet from /home/giuseppe/jdk1.7.0_15/jre/lib/rt.jar]
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/PDDocument
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2451)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2694)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1622)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(LauncherHelper.java:494)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:486)
[Loaded java.util.Objects from /home/giuseppe/jdk1.7.0_15/jre/lib/rt.jar]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
... 6 more
[Loaded java.lang.Shutdown from /home/giuseppe/jdk1.7.0_15/jre/lib/rt.jar]
[Loaded java.lang.Shutdown$Lock from /home/giuseppe/jdk1.7.0_15/jre/lib/rt.jar]
```

So, my question: why the jvm load classes from a jar when no one is really requiring it?

Comment: Did you try your test with a stub class *not located* in the same JAR you are trying to avoid loading?

Comment: @Perception I was about to ask the same thing

Comment: do you need Neos.jar only to get added to the classpath ? if so why use `-jar` and not `-classpath` ? AFAK `-jar` also sets the classpath to and only to the jar specified and a main class is searched in the manifest file.

Answer (score 3):

Your command line is running the main class from the Neos.jar, *not* your test class. To achieve this, replace `-jar` with `-cp` in your command line.

Comment: You are rigth, of course. I already noticed that I tryed with -classpath, and ineed it works. Still I cannot understand what is wrong: if I change main-class in `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` in order to run my test class, I get the same error. See update.